# Python Script doesn't create file

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

So I tried making something like a password vault, where the file pw.txt should be created if it doesnt exist. For some reason it doesnt work. Please help guys!

```
import os.path
import os


def create_file():
    if os.path.exists("D:\\Libaries\\Documents\\resources_py\\pw.txt"):
        pass
    else:
        file = open("pw.txt", 'w')
        file.close()


create_file()
```

Comment: In what directory are you running this program? The call to open() will create a new file in the directory in the current working directory, which is the directory in which the program is run by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found my mistake I forgot to change the path here:

from

```
file = open("pw.txt", 'w')
```

to

```
file = open("D:\\Libaries\\Documents\\resources_py\\pw.txt", 'w')
```

Still thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

Ran the code and it seemed to work just fine for me, the only difference possible is that the os.path.exists() is returning as true which means the file wouldn't be created.

You should probably look at what the os.path.exists() is returning after you run the function and go from there